# Поиск "ботов" и их сообщений

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, поиск, бот

Имеется проект в котором слишком часто регистрируются боты и спамят как только могут.

Есть ли решение для поиска ботов и их сообщений?

Регистрируют примерно похожие имена (admin1,admin2,admin,...,adminN)
Сообщения у них тоже одинакового содержания. На данный момент имеется регулярка для борьбы с пиаром, которая сдерживает их более менее, но из-за частых обходов и выпуска новых фиксов, регулярка уже превышает 1000 символов в длину. По факту уже идет словарь в регулярке.

Есть ли какое-то готовое решение для борьбы с такой проблемой? Предполагается, что сообщения начнут видоизменяться и хотелось бы иметь возможность анализировать предыдущие сообщения бота, чтобы выявлять определенный % схожести и блокировать их.

Желательно решение на Java.

Comment: В форме регистрации поставьте оригинальную капчу :)

Comment: @Visman, дело скорее не в капчи. Человек зайдет и быстро нарегает 100 аккаунтов. А дальше флуд с этих аккаунтов. Нужно что-то похожее на нейронную сеть для ловли ботов и их сообщений.

Comment: Если регистрация делается вручную, а отправка происходит с помощью ботов - то добавьте на кнопку отправки невидимую капчу - невидимый слой над кнопкой submit. Клик мышью по прозрачному месту над кнопкой приводит к отправке, а клик по самой кнопке - к игнорированию сообщения (и репорту вам: "такой-то юзер - потенциальный спамер или сайт по кусочкам ковыряет")
Вот дельная ссылка по теме - https://habrahabr.ru/post/151084/

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. часто боты регистрируются с IP зарубежных стран (чаще - стран "третьего мира"), я не так давно принял решение заблокировать определённые диапазоны IP по подсетям в настройках Apache. Это отсекло большое количество не только ботов, но и вредителей, пытающихся искать директории phpMyAdmin и т.п.
Кроме того, я добавил функционал ответа на простые вопросы (с ротацией вопросов) при регистрации. Потенциальный пользователь легко ответит на вопрос (у меня узкоспециализированный ресурс по Linux, спрашиваю про семейства дистрибутивов), а злоумышленник, даже если он человек, вряд ли станет искать ответ.
На всякий случай приведу здесь часть конфига, в котором я блокирую диапазоны IP (когда делал, нашёл эти списки где-то в Сети). Решение, может, и не стопроцентное, но мне помогло.

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
# AfriNIC:
Deny from 41 102 105 197
# APNIC:
Deny from 1 14 27 36 39
Deny from 42.0.0.0/7
Deny from 49
Deny from 58.0.0.0/7
Deny from 60.0.0.0/7
Deny from 101 103 106
Deny from 110.0.0.0/7
Deny from 112.0.0.0/5
Deny from 120.0.0.0/6
Deny from 124.0.0.0/7
Deny from 126 133 175 180
Deny from 182.0.0.0/7
Deny from 202.0.0.0/7
Deny from 210.0.0.0/7
Deny from 218.0.0.0/7
Deny from 220.0.0.0/6
# LACNIC:
Deny from 177 179 181
Deny from 186.0.0.0/7
Deny from 189
Deny from 190.0.0.0/7
Deny from 200.0.0.0/7
# Networks:
Deny from 3 6 9 11 13 15
Deny from 16.0.0.0/6
Deny from 20.0.0.0/7
Deny from 22 25 26
Deny from 28.0.0.0/7
Deny from 30 33
Deny from 34.0.0.0/7
Deny from 38 40 44 47 48
Deny from 51
Deny from 52.0.0.0/6
Deny from 56.0.0.0/7
Deny from 214.0.0.0/7
```

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, но только у нас пользователи с России, СНГ, Часть Европы и небольшая часть Америка. Поэтому вариант хоть и хороший, но не подойдет.